# Is it possible to modify a support .js file in a web application by injection?

Tags: web-application, javascript, injection

Let's say there is a web application needing a JavaScript support file .js to be loaded in the head of the html document.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="file.js"></script>
    <title>example</title>
  </head>
  <body>
          [...]
  </body>
</html>
```

Would it be possible to modify it with an injection attack, provided of course the web application is vulnerable to injections ? I can't understand how would it be possible to modify a script needed before.

Comment: You might want to describe more accurately what kind of "injection attack" you mean exactly, because there are quite a lot of different kinds of attacks which have "injection" in their name.

Comment: I'm sorry, I understand I haven't been specific enough. The problem is that I'm trying to figure out possible attack scenarios out of an abstract analysis on a paper. The content on the paper says "JavaScript injection overwrites file.js" there aren't other details about. Since I think the file should be on the client, I think it may actually refer to XSS.

Answer (score 1):

Just to ensure we use the right terminology, it should be noted that when talking about web-application vulnerabilities, injection attacks usually refer to  [A1-Injection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2013-A1-Injection) as defined in the OWASP Top Ten classification.

That being said, the answer to your question is yes. Providing the web-application is prone to injection attacks, an attack scenario could be the following:

> The attacker sends a malicious input to the web server that in turn
>   passes it to an interpreter (e.g. php) which includes it in a request
>   and executes it. The malicious input is then executed on the web
>   server, and if the JS file permissions allows it, the code executed ([the payload](http://www.securityfocus.com/glossary/P)) could
>   modify the JS file with an arbitrary content. This modified JS file would then be served to every client requesting this web page.

To simplify, an injection attack can potentially gives an attacker the ability to execute arbitrary commands on the victim server, resulting in files and/or data modification.

Comment: I think my source may be talking about XSS, I've replied a comment on the OP.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about modifying the external javascript file called "file.js" then yes, it is possible to make some modifications to it by using a debugger in your browser of choice. I would start by changing variables in the console of interesting bits of Javascript and adding a breakpoint and running the debugger to see what the outcome is.  I use breakpoints and the debugger to modify variables in javascript in order to produce an unexpected outcome. Let's say the application is using a variable called "is_admin=false" with Javascript. I will first change the variable to "is_admin=true" and continue after my breakpoint in hopes that they are using Javascript in all of the wrong ways to segregate admin rights.